# Finding a gps locations near another one based on a dynamic radius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoding

I have a`GpsLocation` model, this model has a `latitude`, a `longitude` and a `radius` property.

I want to find a GpsLocation based on its latitude and longitude and radius.

So lets say i am on location [52, 4], i want to find a GpsLocation instance that has these exact coordinates or is `radius` meters away.

I am using the `geocoder` gem but the `near` function does not do the job. Also tried monkey patching the near function so i can use a database column instead of a variable inside the query but still no luck, there are some mechanics that transform the lat/long to a range when providing a radius parameter.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the distance between two points on a sphere can be done using the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). There is a gem called [haversine](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/haversine) that can help. Or, if you're using PostgreSQL, there is also the [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/earthdistance.html) module.

However, you may find it easier to relax your definition of "near" somewhat, as dealing with circles can be annoying. Instead, consider using squares or rectangles.

Say you define "near" as within 10 miles. If you treat that as a plus or minus factor around the latitude and longitude of a given point, then you can do a simple query to find all nearby points at once, rather than a series of Haversine calculations. You query might look something like this:

```
# Only accurate in the U.S.
MILES_PER_LATITUDE = 69.0
MILES_PER_LONGITUDE = 55.0

min_latitude = thisLocation.latitude - (10.0 / MILES_PER_LATITUDE)
max_latitude = thisLocation.latitude + (10.0 / MILES_PER_LATITUDE)
min_longitude = thisLocation.longitude - (10.0 / MILES_PER_LONGITUDE)
max_longitude = thisLocation.longitude + (10.0 / MILES_PER_LONGITUDE)

nearby_points = GpsLocation.where(latitude: min_latitude..max_latitude).where(longitude: min_longitude..max_longitude)
```